# Maximal ordinal embeddable into poset of functions under eventual Domination

Tags: set-theory

Consider the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. We can impose a partial order on this set by saying that $f>g$ if $f(n)>g(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$. By a diagonalization argument, it can be shown that one can embed $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal in this Poset. Since the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ it is clear that one can not embed $\omega_2$ if the continuum hypothesis is true. In general what is the smallest ordinal one can not embed. In particular, is there an embedding of $\omega_1+1$ in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest such ordinal is $\omega_2$. I do not want to type much so I'll give you an excellent reference: Problem 24, Chapter 11, P. Komjath and V. Totik - Problems and theorems in classical set theory.

Comment: Maybe add some details, references, *some* justification except taking your word for it? :-)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was being lazy to type the answer but I just found a reference. Although I think this should still count as a good exercise.

Comment: 97.48% of the questions on this site should count as a good exercise. Well, the majority might not be *good*, but nonetheless the point stands.

Comment: I agree although I do not know how u came up with those numbers.

Comment: I made them up, of course. But it's fine, you can just take my word for it! :-)

Comment: You are off by .11%. Take my word for it.

Comment: The following paper of Farah has many interesting results:
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm151/fm15115.pdf